# How to create a method to validate the range of an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, methods

I have an object with some properties. I want to create a method that returns if the position of an array is in range, but I didn't know how to create it.
(I'm trying to make the Minesweeper in AngularJS so this code is inside a .factory)

My code looks like:

```
var tableSquare = function(num_rows, num_bombs){
        this.numRows = num_rows;
        this.numBombs = num_bombs;
        this.positions = new Array(numRows);
        for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            this.positions[i] = new Array(numRows);
        }
};
```

Now I have a working function inRange (values must be >=0 and < range of the array):

```
var inRange = function(i,j, range){
    if (i>=0 && i<= range-1 && j>=0 && j<=range-1)
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

So I can look if an element of my array is in range, I use it lik this (numBombs its a property from an object I had insert in each tableSquare.positions):

```
if (inRange(i-1,j-1,this.numRows)) this.positions[i-1][j-1].numBombs += 1; //up left
```

I want a method like:

```
tableSquare.prototype.inRange = function(){
    //I don't know how to read here i and j
    //in this.positions[i][j]
};
```

So I may use this function making:

```
if (this.positions[i-1][j-1].inRange()) this.positions[i-1][j-1].numBombs += 1;
```

How can I create this inRange method? Thanks ;)

Comment: Are you overdoing the OO here? What does this tableSquare need to do? Doesn't your existing inRange function already do a perfectly good job of checking the bounds?

Comment: Hi Adrian, inRange works perpectly, I'm tryng to learn AngularJS and so OO Javascript. That's why I want to know how to do it. I'm learning creating this Minesweeper

Comment: But even if you made a tableSquare class, its inRange function would be superfluous, because if you've found a tableSquare object to bang on, then obviously you are in range.

Comment: Yes, but now I use the inRange function to get all squares around the one who has a bomb. If the bomb is in position [0][0] there are no squares upper or in left positions, so I have to know if their exists before access its properties. Now I'm using inRange inside the angular.factory, but I will need to validate a range in the controller too, so if its a methos of the class I haven't to duplicate inRange function in the controller. In the controller when a square is clicked I have to read again all squares around clicked one.

Comment: Do not forget that your current tableSquare object is the one that has the .inRange() function, and not the array element objects (which would be your cell objects?). To achieve what you desire you would have to define your cell object, and to add the inRange() function there.

Comment: You proposed an inRange method with no parameters. That can only say if "this" is inRange and of course it is if it exists at all. How about a getNeighbours() method? Anyway, are you seriously saying that angular won't let you call a global function? How's it gonna stop you?

Comment: Tiago, can't insert inRange in may cell objetc becouse if its out of range inRange is undefined

Comment: Thanks Adrian, getNeighbours() method it's a goog idea becouse I have to find them many times. I have just add it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableSquare should be

```
 var tableSquare = function(num_rows, num_bombs){
    this.numRows = num_rows;
    this.numBombs = num_bombs;
    this.positions = new Array(this.numRows);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
        this.positions[i] = new Array(this.numRows);
    }
    this.inRange = function(i,j, range){
      if (i>=0 && i<= range-1 && j>=0 && j<=range-1)
         return true;
      return false;
    };
};
```

and then u should create an object of tableSquare to do yr operations.

```
 var objectOne= new tableSquare(4,4)
```

you can call inRange() as follows

```
objectOne.inRange(1,2,3)
```

Learn javascript here :

1 ) http://eloquentjavascript.net/

2.) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: Thanks nitin. I want to use inRange with positions. your solution is similar as my function but called from the object.

Comment: you can pass positions to inRange, inRange is taking arguments now

Comment: (excuse me for my delay, I do not get notifications of replies to email)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments. What I wanted was something like this:

```
object.positions[1][4].inRange()
```

This inRange function should read 1 and 4 an the length of positions and position[0] and verify if they are in to de array. I coudn't fount how to read this index (really I did it, but adding this coords to the objetc inside positios,s o duplicating information).

So I use Adeian May's solution "getNeighbours()" as follow:

```
var tableSquare = function(num_rows, num_bombs){
    this.numRows = num_rows;
    this.numBombs = num_bombs;

    this.positions = new Array(num_rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
        this.positions[i] = new Array(num_rows);

    this.findingNeighbors = function (i, j) {
        var rowLimit = this.positions.length-1;
        var columnLimit = this.positions[0].length-1;
        var neighbors = [];

        for(var x = Math.max(0, i-1); x <= Math.min(i+1, rowLimit); x++)
            for(var y = Math.max(0, j-1); y <= Math.min(j+1, columnLimit); y++)
                if(x !== i || y !== j)
                    neighbors.push([x,y]);

        return neighbors;
    };
};
```

and call it as follow, so I only work with neighbors and don't have to verify if they are in range:

```
 neighbors = this.findingNeighbors(i,j).slice();
 for (x = 0; x < neighbors.length; x++)
    this.positions[neighbors[x][0]][neighbors[x][1]].numBombs +=1;
```

Thats working, but still don't know if it's posible to read index in the array without passing parameters, like:

```
(seudocode)
table.positions.inRange = function(){
    var position x = read first index of the array (positions[x])
    var position y = read second index of the array (positions[y])
    lenght-x = positions.length
    and so on...
```

Then using xxxxx.positions[1][4].inRange() I could read this "1" index and "4" index.
    }